Antialiased filled circle sdl2
Unsure about how to render a filled circle that is antialiased in SDL2.
I have tried using sdl_gfx but there isn't a function for filled antialiased circle to my knowledge. Is there something I'm missing in sdl_gfx or do I need to write my own code to make an aa filled circle?

https://www.ferzkopp.net/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/Docs/html/_s_d_l__gfx_primitives_8h.html#aee66c744f9fbe58c9f93ad33375373c3?

@Nelfeal This works for a non-filled circle, but I need a filled one

Fill it with filledCircleColor?
